# How can I print article author profile picture?

Tags: theming, users

I have a blog where basic author information needs to be printed out.

Basically, I want to print author name and profile picture in my article teaser template.

I tried googling but none of the answers seemed to help.

Can I somehow access Author object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this on top of your `node.html.twig` or similar template

```
{% 
  set author_pic = {
    '#theme':      'image_style',
    '#style_name': 'thumbnail',
    '#uri':        node.uid.entity.user_picture.entity.uri.value,
    '#attributes': { class: 'authorImg' },
  } 
%}
```

Use this anywhere in the same template you want to output the author image

```
{{ author_pic }}
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine.
Though, I had to delete /* image style name */ comment, otherwise php error occurs.

Comment: Yes you are right I did not realize ... corrected it